# Reset values of hidden part of form

Tags: forms, hidden

We have a form, where some portion of the form is hidden unless user selects any value. In the hidden part there are some complex settings. When the user select empty value in select box and the part is hidden, what should I do?

- remove the settings done by the user
- remember the setting to be able to present them to user again, when he change his mind and change the select box value.

UPDATE

The hidden settings are not sent to server. The form is bigger wizard form and the values are stored to DB only when the user clicks next and the setting are visible. In the setting counts of some tickets are set using some spinners.

For me hidding the part means I don't want them, the value of remeber data is not to force user to fill it again when he chages his mind.

Comment: I think we're going to need more context for this one; why are parts of the form hidden? Is it important that the user adjusts or sees the hidden settings? Are the settings saved after each change or does the user have to submit the form first? Anything else you can think of that will give us some insight about how the form is being used and how the business needs the form to be used. (in any case, changing user inputs without notifying the user is extremely bad)

Comment: My vote is "remember". Why make someone retype if they accidentally hid, or changed their mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember it while the user is still working in the wizard, because they may still want to use it (maybe they are just trying different things in the wizard, so would be annoyed if you deleted content just because they hid it again).

However, at the point the wizard is complete and now submitted, you need to make a decision whether any hidden completed info still has any relevance, i.e. if not then it should be discarded.

Comment: Agree entirely. 'Hide' is different from 'Clear'